# VBA - don't copy paste data based on information

Tags: excel, vba

I've created code that base on "add line" in column A insert row below. As example if we have in row A10 "add line" then it inserts row in A11.

Next base on this I want to copy and paste special for columns E:H in newly created row.

Code that I created you can find below. Unfortunately it works only for one position - meaning if I have "add line" in row A10, A13, A20 it copy-paste only for A11 and rest remain unchanged.

To be precise A14 should have formulas from A13 and A21 from A20.
Could you guide me, what I did wrong?

```
Sub PasteFormulasBelowAddLine()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim addLineRows() As Long
    Dim addLineCount As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input Sheet_wo_Main Sum Lin (3)")
    
    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    
    ' Initialize variables
    addLineCount = 0
    
    ' Loop through column A to find "add line" and store row numbers in array
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = "add line" Then
            addLineCount = addLineCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve addLineRows(1 To addLineCount)
            addLineRows(addLineCount) = i
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Paste formulas in rows below "add line"
    For i = 1 To addLineCount
        ' Check if the row below "add line" exists and is not empty
        If addLineRows(i) < lastRow Then
            ' Copy formulas from the row containing "add line"
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(addLineRows(i), "E"), ws.Cells(addLineRows(i), "H")).Copy
            ' Paste formulas into the row below
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(addLineRows(i) + 1, "E"), ws.Cells(addLineRows(i) + 1, "H")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Clear clipboard
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Example:
[Starting excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghR1h.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPUdo.jpg)

Comment: `copy and paste special for columns E:H` Do you mean paste formulas? `A14 should have formulas from A14` is the 2nd `A14` a typo?

Comment: `A21 from A20` `I have "add line" in row A10, A13, A20` Cell A20 doesn't have formulas. What the expected formula on cell A21? I guess formulas on the inserted row are from the below row. Is it right?

Comment: Check that there are no leading or trailing spaces with `add line`. To eliminate either LTRIM, RTRIM or INSTR can be tried.

Comment: Yes, I want to paste formulas - but it should have updated cells reference. 
We insert row below "add line". Rows where "add line" is includes formulas that are needed to be copied and pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Row insertion shifts all below rows. Looping should be in reverse order.
- Assign formulas is more efficient than copy/paste.

```vb
Sub PasteFormulasBelowAddLine()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim addLineRows() As Long
    Dim addLineCount As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input Sheet_wo_Main Sum Lin (3)")
    
    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    
    ' Initialize variables
    addLineCount = 0
    
    ' Loop through column A to find "add line" and store row numbers in array
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = "add line" Then
            addLineCount = addLineCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve addLineRows(1 To addLineCount)
            addLineRows(addLineCount) = i
            Debug.Print i  ' debug code
        End If
    Next i

    ' Paste formulas in rows below "add line"
    For i = addLineCount To 1 Step -1
        ' Check if the row below "add line" exists and is not empty
        If addLineRows(i) <= lastRow Then
            ws.Rows(addLineRows(i) + 1).Insert
            ' Copy formulas from the row containing "add line"
            With ws.Cells(addLineRows(i), 3)
                .Offset(1).Value = .Value ' Update Col C
            End With
            ' Update formulas on Col E:H 
            With ws.Range(ws.Cells(addLineRows(i), "E"), ws.Cells(addLineRows(i), "H"))
                .Resize(2).Formula = .Formula
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: In the OP code there are no row insertion that cannot be the reason.

Comment: It doesn't work. Still it adds only formulas in "top" comment "add line". 
Further "add line" are ignored and formuls are not included.

Comment: I've updated the code. Run it and check the output in VBE Immedaite window. The missing `add line` rows may be not catched.

Comment: If I use macro that insert rows, then it's working base on "add line". 
It dosen't work for copy-pasting formulas. If I delete "add line" on top, then it recognize next "add line"...

Comment: What's the output in VBE Immedaite window?

Comment: Output is 10 and 13 so lines where "add lines" are (before inserting rows).

Comment: Why is `20` not in the output? Please edit your post to share sample data and expected output. 
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Data shared. 20 is not in the output as I'm currently testing on 10 and 13.

Comment: It inserts row below 10 and includes forlumas correctly
It ignores "add line in row 13...

Comment: Row 13 is the last row, pls try `If addLineRows(i) <= lastRow Then`