# Error in VBA code for inserting last row in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create similar project, as it was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78022564/vba-dont-copy-paste-data-based-on-information)
In column A I have "Add line" and macro needs to insert row, copy&paste formats and keep additiona data if neccessary.
If the "Add line" is in the middle of range, then everything works. If it's last line, it adds 5 rows instead of one.
I've tried to use:

```
If addLineRows(i) <= lastRow Then
```

but it doesn't work for me. Formats and formulas after adding row are downloaded from "2a_Input Background" so "master data" where all formats and formulas are saved.

*Before adding*
[image: Before adding]
*After adding*
[image: After adding]

```
Sub AddS2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim addLineRows() As Long
    Dim addLineCount As Long
    Dim mainPositions As Integer
    Dim subPositions As Integer
    Dim totalRows As Integer
    Dim j As Integer ' Declare j here
    Dim currentRow As Long ' Declare currentRow here

    mainPositions = Sheets("1_Selections").Range("D20").Value
    subPositions = Sheets("1_Selections").Range("D21").Value
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2_Input")
    
    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Initialize variables
    addLineCount = 0

    ' Loop through column A to find "add line" and store row numbers in array
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = "Add line" Then
            addLineCount = addLineCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve addLineRows(1 To addLineCount)
            addLineRows(addLineCount) = i
            Debug.Print i  ' debug code
            
            ' Initialize currentRow for inserting S1 and S2
            currentRow = i + 1
            
            ' Insert row and copy formulas
            If i = lastRow Then
                ' If "Add line" is in the last row, insert only one row below it
                ws.Rows(lastRow + 1).Insert
                Sheets("2a_Input Background").Range("A8:BP8").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A" & currentRow)
                currentRow = lastRow + 1 ' Update currentRow
            Else
                ' If "Add line" is not in the last row, insert a row below the current row
                ws.Rows(i + 1).Insert
                currentRow = i + 1 ' Update currentRow
            End If
            
        
        ' Loop through sub positions
        Dim k As Integer
        For k = 1 To subPositions
            ' Copy S2 data
            Sheets("2a_Input Background").Range("A8:X8").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A" & currentRow)
            Sheets("2a_Input Background").Range("Z8").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("Z" & currentRow)
            Sheets("2a_Input Background").Range("AC8:BA8").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AC" & currentRow)
            Sheets("2a_Input Background").Range("BL8:BP8").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("BL" & currentRow)
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        Next k
    End If
Next i
    
    ' Clear contents of column A starting from A1
    ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: What's `subPositions`? Because you're adding values through that it seems as well.

Comment: In file I have Main (S1) and Subpositon (S2). Base on those I need to have different formats. Main in general summarisies the subpositions.

Comment: Is the value by any chance `4`? Since you're looping and adding values on empty rows (aka adding rows).

Comment: Which value? 
If I add row in between then it adds one row,  After adding last row, script goes to "' Copy S2 data" and then indeed somehow in treats each line separately - adding new rows

Comment: What is the value you give `subPositions` here `subPositions = Sheets("1_Selections").Range("D21").Value`. Because you're looping there and thus giving the extra following rows (due to `currentRow)` also values.